# 2D Procedural Generation

Tags: c#, monogame, procedural-generation

I'm currently trying to implement procedurally generated tilemaps for an overworld. I'm as far as generating noise and building the tilemaps using different ranges within the generated noise. However, they're very crude as each different 'biome' is just one tile. What is the best way to implement the detailing and edges of each biome? e.g flowers/trees/etc spread out in a forest biome, beach-to-water transition tiles between beach and ocean biome, etc.

For some context, I built an engine in MonoGame with a friend of mine. We implemented a chunk loading system for dynamic generation and infinite scrolling with no load screens(not exactly state of the art, I know, but I was proud of it). Each chunk is 50x50 tiles, and there are 9 chunks loaded at any given time. When the player moves chunks in any direction, the chunks on the opposite corner are unloaded and new ones are loaded in the direction the player is walking. Since the player is starting on the opposite of where chunks are being generated, it hasn't been a problem thus far as the maps are big enough that they're done generating by the time the player gets to them. I'm not sure whether the current method I have in mind is going to change this or not.

Anyway, I'm thinking that I need to determine within each biome a specific set of tiles and generate noise for each biome instance to determine placement of 'detail' tiles specific to that biome. For the edges, I'd just loop through each adjacent tile to determine whether it's a different biome. If so, use the transition tile. However, the whole idea seems very inefficient as that's a ton of noise to generate as well as looping through 7500 tiles every time the player moves chunks. I've been trying to think of a better method, but this is my first foray into procedural generation and I haven't been able to find much online that talks about anything more in-depth than generating noise and using that noise to generate chunks of land. Is there a more efficient method I should use or is my next step going to be optimizing? I can't imagine my method is going to be very efficient or practical due to how much I'm going to be looping through every tile. Anyone have any ideas or suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

One idea:

- Use noise to generate height, temperature, rain, ... for each chunk
- Use generated values to determine the biome for each chunk
- For each tile interpolate the generated of the surrounding chunks
- Use the interpolated values to select ground textures, plants, ...

That should generate smooth borders between biomes and also different chunks with the same biome can have a different feel.